# Creating a wrapper for button with confirmation popup components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a button component with the following props:

- `onClick: () => void` - Triggers button click
- `Caption: string` - Button text

And a `Popup` component with the following props:

- `onCancelPopup: () => void` - Placed in the cancel button
- `onOkPopup: () => void` - Fires if the user selects OK
- `IsPopupVisible: boolean` - Determines popup visibility
- `PopupMessage: string` - Like a confirmation message

I'm trying to create a wrapper component composed of Button and Popup. Using this wrapper I want to trigger the popup dialog. I plan to use this in a page with multiple buttons, each of which will trigger its own confirmation popup.

The easiest way to do this is wrap it in a `BtnConfirm` wrapper component as follows:

```
<>
    <Button onClick={this.props.showPopup} Caption={this.props.Caption} />
    <Popup IsPopupVisible={this.props.Visible} onCancelPopup={this.props.hidePopup}>
        {this.props.PopupMessage}
    </Popup>
</>
```

Say `CallingComponent` is using `<BtnConfirm />`. Then it will need to define `Visible` in its state and show/hide it in separate functions
as follows:

```
showPopup = () => setState({ Visible: true })
hidePopup = () => setState({ Visible: false })
popupOkClick = () => alert("OK Clicked");
```

And `<BtnConfirm />` will have to receive all the props of both `Button` and `Popup` as `props` in the `CallingComponent`.

My question is, if I have mutiple instances of `BtnConfirm` in `CallingComponent`, wouldn't that mean I'll need to define `Visible` states for each of them? Is there a better way of achieving the same result without having to do this?